# Interpreting the Kurtosis Formula Using Moors Way

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, descriptive-statistics, z-score, kurtosis

I was studying Kurtosis from this [site](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/04/11/moments/) and found this way to interpret the kurtosis formula, but I don't fully understand **what they mean by the variance of Z^2 around its mean of 1, and why that might be a helpful way to view the kurtosis formula.**

Also, it would be better if you can derive for me their kurtosis formula in more detailed steps, especially how E(Z^2)^2 is transformed into V(Z^2).

Attached is a screenshot of their explanation from the above-mentioned site.

[image]

Comment: Try expanding the square of the r.hs. in equation (30), remembering that $\mathbb{E}[Z] = 0$.

Comment: re "how E(Z^2)^2 is transformed into V(Z^2)": a standard formula for the variance expresses it as the difference between the expected square and the square of the expectation.  Add the latter to both sides.

Comment: Moors suggested that this way of looking at kurtosis shows that larger kurtosis arises as either greater tail extension, or by greater concentration toward the mean. He was right on the first count, but wrong on the second: the arrangement of the data/density/mass within $\pm \sigma$ of $\mu$ has very little effect on kurtosis.